# Select from two tables with group by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

Table t1:

```
id | date_click
 1 | 2016-02-31 17:17:23
 2 | 2016-03-31 12:11:21
 3 | 2016-03-31 13:13:23
```

So from this table I want to get count field `Id` for each day.

For this I use next query:

```
SELECT date_format(date_click, '%Y-%m-%d') as date_click_event
     , COUNT(id) as count_click 
  FROM t1 
 GROUP 
    BY date_click_event 
 ORDER 
    BY date_click_event DESC;
```

It's work good.

So next table is t2.

```
id | count | date_sent
 1 |    33 | 2016-02-31 11:12:23
 2 |    22 | 2016-03-31 14:11:22
 3 |    11 | 2016-03-31 13:12:13
```

To select data by date from this table I use next query:

```
SELECT date_format(date_sent, '%Y-%m-%d') as date_sent_push
     , SUM(count) as count_sent 
  FROM t2 
 GROUP 
    BY date_sent_push 
 ORDER 
    BY date_sent_push DESC 
 LIMIT 100;
```

It's also work good. So my purpose is merge these two queries into one `SELECT` that next I can write in php one tables with count of `Id` by date from table `t1` and with count of `count` field from table `t2` by date.

When I try next query:

```
SELECT date_format(t2.date_sent, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date_sent_push
     , SUM(t2.count) as count_sent
     , COUNT(t1.id) as count_click 
  FROM t2
     , t1 
 WHERE date_format(t2.date_sent, '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(t1.date_click, '%Y-%m-%d') 
 GROUP 
    BY date_sent_push 
 ORDER 
    BY date_sent_push 
  DESC 
 LIMIT 100;
```

It's not work. What I do wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with "It's not work" ..?  error ? wrong result?  .. evenatually show expected result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you should UNION these results and then group by days and select aggregate fields. Also you can JOIN these queries but it can be a problem if some days miss in one of two tables:

```
SELECT date_sent_push, 
       MAX(count_click) as count_click,
       MAX(count_sent) as count_sent 
FROM
(SELECT date_format(date_click, '%Y-%m-%d') as date_sent_push
     , COUNT(id) as count_click
     , NULL as count_sent
  FROM t1 
  GROUP BY date_sent_push 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date_format(date_sent, '%Y-%m-%d') as date_sent_push
     , NULL as count_click
     , SUM(count) as count_sent 
  FROM t2 
  GROUP 
    BY date_sent_push 
) as t3
GROUP BY date_sent_push
```

<kbd>[SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75ef9b/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
use this code

(SELECT date_format(date_sent, '%Y-%m-%d') as date_sent_push, SUM(count) as count_sent FROM t2 GROUP BY date_sent_push ORDER BY date_sent_push DESC LIMIT 100)
UNION
(SELECT date_format(t2.date_sent, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date_sent_push, SUM(t2.count) as count_sent, COUNT(t1.id) as count_click FROM t2, t1 WHERE date_format(t2.date_sent, '%Y-%m-%d')=date_format(t1.date_click, '%Y-%m-%d') GROUP BY date_sent_push ORDER BY date_sent_push DESC LIMIT 100)
```

Comment: It's return error: #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns , but count of dates in two tables equals

Comment: Union requires equal no. of columns So the no. of column from 1st select query must be equal to the no. of column from 2nd query.