# 2 tables : all date group by date DESC

Tags: php, mysql

I'm reading [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37044565/select-from-two-tables-with-group-by-date) which interests me the most but I must be making a mistake somewhere

I have 2 tables :

1. hta with colonn ta1, ta2, ta3, dateb (which is datetime of row)
2. biometrie with colonn taille, poids, date_biometrie (dateime of row)

I try to have a mix a 2 tables like this : .
[image]

Actually everything works fine with 1 table. But it's not working when I try to mix with the second table.

```
<!-- Timelime example  -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <!-- The time line -->
  </div>
<div class="timeline">
<?php
session_start();
$username = isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : NULL;

try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***;charset=utf8', '***', '***');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}

// Everything work with 1 table like this :
// $reponsem3 = $bdd->query("SELECT ta1, ta2, ta3, DATE_FORMAT(dateb, '%d %b') AS nndate, DATE_FORMAT(dateb, '%H h %i') AS nnheure FROM hta WHERE username='$username' ORDER BY dateb DESC LIMIT 0,30");

// but when i try mix both, it doesn't work
$reponsem3 = $bdd->query("SELECT nndate, n1, n2, n3
FROM (SELECT ta1 AS n1, ta2 AS n2, ta3 AS n3, DATE_FORMAT(dateb, '%d %b') AS nndate, DATE_FORMAT(dateb, '%H h %i') AS nnheure FROM hta WHERE username='$username' GROUP BY date UNION ALL SELECT poids AS n1, taille AS n2, DATE_FORMAT(date_biometrie, '%d %b') AS nndate FROM biometrie WHERE username='$username' GROUP BY date_biometrie) ORDER BY nndate");

$nndate = '';

while ($donneesm3 = $reponsem3->fetch())
{ 
  if ($nndate != $donneesm3['nndate'])
  {
 ?>
    <!-- timeline time label MOIS PAIRE-->
    <?php echo "<div class='time-label'>
      <span class='bg-secondary'>".$donneesm3['nndate']."</span>
    </div>"; } ?>
    <!-- /.timeline-label -->
              
    <!-- timeline item RESULTAT AMT-->
    <div>
      <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt bg-blue"></i>
      <div class="timeline-item"> <span class="time"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i> <?php 
        echo ($donneesm3['nnheure']);
    ?> </span>
        <h3 class="timeline-header">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8" align="center">
              <td>
              </td>
              /
              <td>
              <?php echo $donneesm3['n2']; ?></td>
              <td>
              <?php 
                echo ($donneesm3['n3']);
              ?></td>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4" align="rigth">
              <a class="btn btn-tool"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> </a>
              <a class="btn btn-tool"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4" align="rigth">
            <a class="btn btn-tool"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> </a>
            <a class="btn btn-tool"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
              
  <?php
  $nndate = $donneesm3['nndate'];
}
$reponsem3->closeCursor();

?>
</div>
```

Comment: [What do you mean "It doesn't work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work)

Comment: nothing appears on my page. no error either

Comment: Please indent your code following to this : https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/1213575